# SD Card removal intents not working

Tags: android, android-sdcard, intentfilter, android-broadcastreceiver

first time posting here I hope I do it right. I'm trying to detect when the SD Card is removed from a device, my broadcast receiver works fine on an old ICS tablet (I'm able to get the MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, BAD_REMOVAL, etc, intent actions) but in another tablet with **android 4.2** nothing happens when I remove the SD Card, none of the following intent actions are broadcasted:

- MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL
- MEDIA_EJECT
- MEDIA_REMOVED
- MEDIA_UNMOUNTED

I have only found 1 related question to this here, but the solution was adding the dataScheme "file" which I already tried. Here is my code:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver;
    private IntentFilter sdCardIntentFilter;

    sdCardIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_REMOVED);
    sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL);
    sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_EJECT);
    sdCardIntentFilter.addDataScheme("file");

    registerReceiver(deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver, sdCardIntentFilter);

    deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                switch (intent.getAction()) {

                    case MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL:
                    case MEDIA_EJECT:
                    case MEDIA_REMOVED:
                    case MEDIA_UNMOUNTED:
                        Log.i("SD CARD REMOVED");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Comment: I didn't added anything in the manifest since I was doing everything programmaticaly, and it seems to work in the old 4.0 tablet. Should I do something there aswell?

Comment: Yes you have to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest. I'll answer one sec.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest like this

```
<application>
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastSDCard">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

Then create a new class with the name `BroadcastSDCard`.class and use that one.

```
public class BroadcastSDCard extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

You can still use your existing code

```
private BroadcastSDCard deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver;
private IntentFilter sdCardIntentFilter;

deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastSDCard();
sdCardIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_REMOVED);
sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL);
sdCardIntentFilter.addAction(MEDIA_EJECT);
sdCardIntentFilter.addDataScheme("file");

registerReceiver(deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver, sdCardIntentFilter);
```

Also don't forget to unregister it in your `onDestroy()` method or you will get leaks.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (deviceCardsBroadcastReceiver!= null)
            unregisterReceiver(updateBroadcast);
    }
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: @NikolasManuelides This is a new class. Make a new class.

Comment: yes, I didn't read well, will try that and report back, thanks.

Comment: ok, I did it like you posted and same results, works on 4.0 tablet, does not work on 4.2 tablet, any other suggestions?  =/

Comment: @NikolasManuelides Only that maybe your 4.2 tablet does not have a external storage. Upgrade your current 4.0 to 4.2 to verify it.

Comment: sadly I cannot, there is no update for this old tablet, but the 4.2 one does have a SD Card which I'm removing to try to trigger the intent action.